# How to use stackdriver trace for an already existing cluster on google cloud?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

So, I'm trying to use Stackdriver Trace for my existing Node.js microservices deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine.

I'm using this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/nodejs). In the documentation, we're asked to add the trace.append OAuth access scope when we create our cluster. However, I'm not creating my cluster at this time. Also, it is mentioned that "Note: You cannot change the access scopes of a cluster after creation."

If that is the case then how can i get my stackdriver trace to work on my already existing cluster?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get Stackdriver Trace to work with an existing cluster if it doesn't have the correct scopes. There's a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/825644/how-to-enable-stackdriver-monitoring-and-stackdriver-trace-on-existing-gke-clust), they suggest:

> if you can port your application on a new Google Container instance, you can always recreate a new cluster and enable the desired Stackdriver services/permissions on its configuration page.

Comment: Since this seems to be a common problem, I have created a Public Issue for this that you can follow [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/134732722)

Comment: Thanks. I starred it